# Webcam setup and usage on Windows CE

Tags: windows-ce, webcam, webcam-capture

I am attempting to get a Microsoft HD-3000 webcam working on Windows CE 4.2 and 6.0.

I have given up with 4.2, but 6.0 certainly looks possible with DirectDraw and the DDrawCameraTest.exe app that can be built from the CE 6 dev environment in VS2005.

I have used a codeplex usb webcam driver (https://cewebcam.codeplex.com/) which detects the camera fine (and I checked the entries are added to the registry), but from the debug info when I run the DDrawCameraTest.exe the process aborts at the following step:

hr = g_DShowCaptureGraph.RunGraph();

where hr is an instantiation of CCaptureFramework.

This obviously means I do not have the directdraw video capture component of CE installed on this particular image, but I do not have control of that.

Question - How can I either install directdraw video capture components to CE 6 on the device (CAB installer etc.) OR can I access a webcam without directdraw?

Answer (score 1):

You may access the camera without DD by calling the driver's IOCTLs directly.
Drivers must support some specific IOCTLs to be able to be accessed from DD and those are documented on MSDN (I don't have a link at the moment and MSDN links change so fast that a google search looking for IOCTLs implemented by the webcam driver may be the best way to find the information you need :))

Comment: Thanks Valter. Do you know of any test applications that access IOCTL's directly. I am very new to C++ and deving this from scratch will be quite a learning curve.

Comment: If I recall correctly there is a sample app in Freescale's BSPs for i.MX chips freely available on their website. Another place to look is the source code of the camera test in the windows CE test kit (you may need to install an evaluation version of Windows CE Platform builder to get it).